# VISSIM COM Interface VehicleNetworkPerformanceMeasurement

Tags: python

I'm using Python to communicate with the VISSIM traffic simulation software using its COM interface.

I'm trying to access the VehicleNetworkPerformanceMeasurement total delay attribute while running a simulation

```
#run vissim
env = win32com.client.Dispatch('Vissim.Vissim.800') 

#load layout,network
env.LoadNet( r'X:\Users\rHalabi\singleIntersection\Ryan.inpx')
env.LoadLayout( r'X:\Users\rHalabi\singleIntersection\Ryan.layx' )

#tell vissim to collect vehicle performance data
env.Net.Evaluation.SetAttValue( 'VehNetPerfCollectData', 1)

#run a few steps
for i in range(10):
    env.Simulation.RunSingleStep()

#collect results
env.Net.VehicleNetworkPerformanceMeasurement.AttValue( 'DelayTot' )
```

The last line returns an error

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'VISSIM.Vissim.800', 'Sub-attribute not specified', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

I've tried other attributes besides 'DelayTot' but none work.  I've followed the documentation and been able to query other objects no problem.

How do I access this data?

Comment: In the last line env.Net.VehicleNetworkPerformanceMeasurement.AttValue( 'DelayTot' ), you should include sub attributes as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out for attributes with sub attributes you need to supply the subattributes in the query.  Here is some example code from the VISSIM documentation for how to query the TravelTimeMeasurements

```
Veh_TT_measurement = Vissim.Net.VehicleTravelTimeMeasurements.ItemByKey(Veh_TT_measurement_number)
# Syntax to get the travel times:
#   Veh_TT_measurement.AttValue('TravTm(sub_attribut_1, sub_attribut_2, sub_attribut_3)')
#
# sub_attribut_1: SimulationRun
#       1, 2, 3, ... Current:     the value of one specific simulation (number according to the tribute "No" of Simulation Runs (see List of Simulation Runs))
#       Avg, StdDev, Min, Max:    aggregated value of all simulations runs: Avg, StdDev, Min, Max
# sub_attribut_2: TimeInterval
#       1, 2, 3, ... Last:        the value of one specific time interval (number of time interval always starts at 1 (first time interval), 2 (2nd TI), 3 (3rd TI), ...)
#       Avg, StdDev, Min, Max:    aggregated value of all time interval of one simulation: Avg, StdDev, Min, Max
#       Total:                    sum of all time interval of one simulation
# sub_attribut_3: VehicleClass
#       10, 20 or All             values only from vehicles of the defined vehicle class number (according to the attribute "No" of Vehicle Classes)
#                                 Note: You can only access the results of specific vehicle classes if you set it in Evaluation > Configuration > Result Attributes
#
# The value of on time interval is the arithmetic mean of all single travel times of the vehicles.
```

Answer (score 0):

Halabi said it exactly.
More specifically, you can query sub-attributes like

```
VNPM = env.Net.VehicleNetworkPerformanceMeasurement.AttValue( 'DelayTot(Current, Tot, All)' )
```

To check if there exists any sub-attributes for attributes you want to use, 'Help' > 'COM Help' on Vissim toolbar will help you.